# How to change an integral clock wise to anticlock wise?

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to to change an integral say $$\int_{C}^{} \frac{-e^{z^{2}}}{\sin 4z}dz $$ with $C$: $|z|=1$ from clock wise to anticlockwise orientation. Can I do it simply by changing the sign to negative at the front?

Comment: Show your attempt.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Suppose you have a parametrization $\gamma: [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ of the path $C$.  By definition, $\displaystyle \int_C f(z) \ dz = \int_a^b f(\gamma(t)) \gamma'(t) \ dt$.  Reversing the orientation will simply change the parametrization of $C$ by having $t$ run from $b$ to $a$ instead of from $a$ to $b$.  Thus, reversing the orientation has the effect:

$$\int_{C^{\text{op}}} f(z) \ dz = \int_b^a f(\gamma(t)) \gamma'(t) \ dt = - \int_a^b f(\gamma(t)) \gamma'(t) \ dt = - \int_C f(z) \ dz$$

where $C^\text{op}$ denotes $C$ with the reverse orientation.